# How i can attach one base64 image in email?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to put a base64 image in attachment when i send a email, but i'm receiving a error.

My function:

The variable with base64 content has name: "foto" in array `$data`

```
        public function avisarAnjos(Request $request){


        $data = array(
            'lat' => $request->lat,
            'lng' => $request->lng,
            'foto' => $request->foto,
            'emailUsuario' => $request->emailUsuario,
            'nomeUsuario' => $request->nomeUsuario,
            'telefoneUsuario' => $request->telefoneContato
        );

        $usuariosAnjos = User::select('email')->where('usuario_anjo', 1)->get();



    for($i=0; $i < count($usuariosAnjos);$i++){
        Mail::send('email', $data, function ($message) use ($usuariosAnjos, $i) {
            $message->from('suporte@cademeupet.net', 'Ei, tem um pet precisando da sua ajuda!')->subject('Precisamos de você!');
            $message->to($usuariosAnjos[$i]['email']);
            $message->attachData(base64_decode($data['foto']['base64']), $data['foto']['fotopetencontrado'], ['mime' => $data['foto']['image/jpeg']]);
        });
    }
    return response()->json("Email enviado com sucesso", 201);
}
```

I'm receiving this error:

> "message": "Undefined variable: data",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to pass `$data` in the `use` closure argument like so : `Mail::send('email', $data, function ($message) use ($data, $usuariosAnjos, $i)`

```
public function avisarAnjos(Request $request){


    $data = array(
        'lat' => $request->lat,
        'lng' => $request->lng,
        'foto' => $request->foto,
        'emailUsuario' => $request->emailUsuario,
        'nomeUsuario' => $request->nomeUsuario,
        'telefoneUsuario' => $request->telefoneContato
    );

    $usuariosAnjos = User::select('email')->where('usuario_anjo', 1)->get();



for($i=0; $i < count($usuariosAnjos);$i++){
    Mail::send('email', $data, function ($message) use ($data, $usuariosAnjos, $i) {
        $message->from('suporte@cademeupet.net', 'Ei, tem um pet precisando da sua ajuda!')->subject('Precisamos de você!');
        $message->to($usuariosAnjos[$i]['email']);
        $message->attachData(base64_decode($data['foto']['base64']), $data['foto']['fotopetencontrado'], ['mime' => $data['foto']['image/jpeg']]);
    });
}
return response()->json("Email enviado com sucesso", 201);
```

Comment: thanks, but now i'm receiving: "message": "Illegal string offset 'base64'",

Comment: do you get it for `$data` variable?

Comment: Probably something wrong with `$data['foto']`, you should dump() it to see what it contains.

Comment: now i can attach the image with this code: $message->attachData($data['foto'], 'fotopetencontrado.jpeg', ['mime' => 'image/jpeg']); but my image is don't preview and when i download it's break

Comment: same problem with base64_decode. I have to substring the initial string? My base64 is: data:image/png;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABA...

Comment: It should work, look on this similar question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948309/how-to-attach-file-to-laravel-5-2-mail-from-base64-format